# how to fix https openid error

Tags: python, django, openid

I am using local https protocol and a fake certificate.

When using `django-openid-auth`, it gives me this error:

```
OpenID failed

OpenID discovery error: Error fetching XRDS document: (60, 'server certificate         verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none')
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I add my fake certificate in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt file and error changed to
                                                                                
    `OpenID failed

    OpenID discovery error: Error fetching XRDS document: (77, 'Problem with the SSL CA cert (path? access rights?)')`

Comment: The error is a error of the CURL library http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html#CURLESSLCACERT. The CURL documentation states that the server you are connecting to has certificate which can not be validated.

When does the error occurs, on what URL?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, in most cases the validators are picky on self-signed certificates.

In general, when using "fake" certificates you should always take the extra step and create a fake CA and sign the fake cert with the CA. If nothing else, this makes your testing be more like a real life scenario.

Here are brief instructions on how to do this with OpenSSL:

1. Create a CA (self signed) `openssl req -x509 -new -out ca.crt -keyout ca.key -days 3650`
2. Create a server key and csr `openssl req -out server.csr -pubkey -new -keyout server.secure.key`
3. Take off the passphrase `openssl rsa -in server.secure.key -out server.key`
4. Sign the server certificate with the CA `openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAcreateserial -out server.crt -days 1825`
5. (For futher certificates, use the existing serial number `openssl x509 -req -in server.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -CAserial ca.srl -out server.crt -days 1825`)

Whenever you have problems with *any* SSL (not just HTTPS) - use raw `openssl` to debug by doing

```
openssl s_verify -connect <hostname>:<portnumber> <options>
```

e.g.

```
openssl s_verify -connect localhost:443 -CAfile myfakeca.pem
```

This usually saves you a lot of trouble figuring out problems with your actual certificates that actually have nothing to do with your code.